# Button not calling function

Tags: javascript, html, button

We are trying to call a function on a button click, but for some reason the button will not call the function. Can anyone tell us why?

```
<body>

<button onclick="instagramclick()">Login to instagram</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test Button</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello World");
}

function instagramclick(){
    alert("button clicked");
    window.location.href = "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=8a612cd650344523808233c0468c80ed&redirect_uri=http://u-ahmed.github.io/HookedUp/&response_type=token";
    var token = window.location.href.substring(43);

    if(token="s_denied&error_reason=user_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request"){
    alert("That's fine, but we can't access your instagram without your permission.");
    }
    else {
    jQuery(function($) {

        function writeToFile(token){
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var fh = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\\instagramtoken.txt");
            fh.WriteLine(", ,"+ token);
            fh.Close();
        }
    });

}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Close your instagramclick function with curly brace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this will helps you.
There was a syntax mistake in the function.

```html
<body>

  <button onclick="instagramclick()">Login to instagram</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Test Button</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      alert("Hello World");
    }

    function instagramclick() {
      alert("button clicked");
      window.location.href = "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=8a612cd650344523808233c0468c80ed&redirect_uri=http://u-ahmed.github.io/HookedUp/&response_type=token";
      var token = window.location.href.substring(43);

      if (token = "s_denied&error_reason=user_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request") {
        alert("That's fine, but we can't access your instagram without your permission.");
      } else {
        jQuery(function($) {

          function writeToFile(token) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var fh = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\\instagramtoken.txt");
            fh.WriteLine(", ," + token);
            fh.Close();
          }
        });

      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, we were really relieved.

Answer (score 0):

Closing bracket of instagramclick functionn is missing thats why click event is not firing

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the close braces on your instagramclick() function.